# Trying to get multiple items from another table with multiple inputs with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that holds some id's on some different pictures. And with those id's I would like to get the picture id's that matches from another table. But I cant seem to get this to work.

Heres is what I got so far:

```
public List<Image> ImagesForSession()
{
    var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var newestSes = newSes.GetNewestSession(userID);

    var imgsOnSes = mtm.GetImagesOnSession(newestSes).Select(i => i.ImgId);

    var imgs = imgSes.GetImageOnId(imgsOnSes).Select(x => x);

    return imgs.ToList();
}
```

What I need in the end is to be able to return all the images to a list, so I can use it as a data source for a repeater.

Here is the method where I find all the images that are on the session

```
public List<MtoMImg> GetImagesOnSession(int sesID)
{
    var query = _db.MtoMImgs.Where(i => i.SessionId == sesID).Select(i => i);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

And last, here is the method where I get the images on the id:

```
public List<Image> GetImageOnId(int ID)
{
    var query = _db.Images.Where(i => i.id == ID).Select(i => i);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: What's the issue ?  Are you trying to get all `ImageSession` `Images`?  If so clarify your opening sentence and use your domain names.

Comment: Small comment to your code `.Select(i => i)` is redundant. And I agree with @Nix - What's the issue

Comment: That code i dont believe compiles either...  `GetImagesOnSession` returns a List.    `GetImageOnId` accepts` an int.

Comment: the problem is that the parameter that GetImageOnId needs is a int, and is getting a IEnum<int> list dunno know how to work around this

Comment: (Voting to close)  I can fix this but I don't feel its the right thing to do.  Look into using `Contains` in your where clause.  Update `GetImageOnId` to take in a `List<int>` .  How large is the list of Images?  If its pretty large then you might want to do a join.  If that is the case I'm interested again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a statement that combines them together.  You need to update the `on` clause to match how the tables are related.  If you are doing EntityFramework this becomes a whole lot simpler.  Because you can probably select the Images directly.

```
public List<Image> GetImageOnId(int sessionID)
{
    return (
      from sessionImage in _db.MtoMImgs
      join  image in _db.Images on sessionImage.ImageId equals image.Id
      where sessionImage.SessionId == sessionID 
      select  image
    ).ToList();
}
```

Option 2 is you just get the images.  Would need to see more of how your data model works, and also would need to be using EF.

```
return _db.Images.Where(x=>x.SessionId== sessionID).ToList();
```